# Error when selecting Billing account in Google API console

Tags: android, google-api, google-maps-android-api-2

I have created a new Google API project and I have enabled Google Maps for Android API in the Google API Console. When I click to manage this API it prompts me to link this project to a billing account. This is expected. However when I choose the billing account from the drop down and Click Select Account I get an indeterminate progress indicator and nothing further happens. When I check the network calls in developer tools (of Google Chrome) I see the following response.

```
[
{
    "data": {
        "billingResourcesMutation": {
            "assignResourceToBillingAccount": null
        }
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
            "errorType": "DATA_FETCHING_EXCEPTION",
            "path": [
                "billingResourcesMutation",
                "assignResourceToBillingAccount"
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "status": {
                    "code": 8,
                    "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                            "reason": "QUOTA_EXCEEDED",
                            "domain": "cloudconsole-pa.googleapis.com/billing"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "path": [],
    "responseContext": {
        "eti": "Ac/7oItaEtCPTayTIAQbhQH/iZ4ybj2a28FQmNoTK5bM0IovMnCBduVy/66YV33fRSVLkak7z7opcU3Fo+HmmK9JIUi0zj/F6DkFF0s2bHiL6/lvPYBCC30U+E8VWwpV+QhB3v//ei+8FNb/z0kWY34Cfcffni811PIEGVbXuQ=="
    }
},
{
    "responseContext": {
        "eti": "Ac/7oIsdiGZBIIbcmBQ3jMsl5TgLAzJCgBpFy6FNJEYJENcVWA1jMc5nqT64E8ajfvycwgFv6HT2kZQ1bxUOwWPIEuD8lmVlYk/knKulD9zpmC2dKUgNcjc0mqIne6UZWLqd15066iE8fpn39yO8pHzuLhqNgHuldAbOlTbx9UzfIqVNYUe8R0pgm4Os1binX6qr6JJPabh/6OJorRFwzMhLuxejda7JshZuF2u7oMhdq/leq+OIwwMfizsOIWdg6YLIzzJLIb3DDNDD97HP5yccEA=="
    }
}
]
```

If I take the advice and click on Quotas in the left hand menu I am asked to select a billing account and the cycle starts again. How might I progress please?

Comment: I believe you should file a support case for help with regards to your issue. As this seems to be not really about programming. To do so, you can go here: https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support And filing a billing support case should suffice.